# Examples on Picard-Lindelöf’s theorem for odes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find an example of ode, $x^{‘}=f(t,x)$, where $f$ does not satisfies Picard-Lindelöf theorem, but it still have unique solution.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can look at Alexander Eremenko's answer to [Solution set of non-unique solutions to First order ODE's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234183/solution-set-of-non-unique-solutions-to-first-order-odes) on MO.

Comment: And if you need a *concrete* example, see, e.g., [Example: f(x,y)
is not Lipschitz in y but still has a unique solution to initial value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688744/example-fx-y-is-not-lipschitz-in-y-but-still-has-a-unique-solution-to-initi/2689055#2689055).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

1. [Osgood's criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Osgood_criterion)
2. $f(t,x)$ is decreasing as a function of $x$ for all $t$.